# Encoder and Decoder size in seq2seq.py tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, encoder, decoder

I have gone through the code for English-French translation which was in tensorflow. I have some questions.

1. Is it necessary that the number of layers and neurons in both encoder and decoder must be same?
2. What is the relation between embedding size of the words and the number of hidden layers? (In `seq2seq_model.py`, embedding size is set equal to the number of hidden neurons). Can we change the size?
3. Where exactly is the code for calculating `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`? (I have gone through the function in `nn.py`, but where exactly is the error calculated?)